# and TestDriven.Net

Tags: c#, tdd, attributes, mstest, testdriven.net

Has anyone experienced any issues with using the mstest attribute [AssemblyInitialize] when running tests with TestDriven.Net?

I've tried 2.14 RTM and 2.22 RTM and neither seem to work for me. When I execute the test, the assembly init method isn't being executed. It's like TD.Net doesn't recongize the attribute.

Any tips/ideas/clues is welcome! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If memory serves TD.NET is built on NUnit and NUnit does not support AssemblyInitialize or AssemblyCleanup (and I don't think it has anything like them).

Comment: Not really similar Arnis - if you want to attach/detach a testing database, setup log4net, or something else where you're willing to take the hit of less good test isolation vs. test-speed having to run it for each fixture is a huge hassle.